# Regular Expression To Match XML String is having start and end tags in C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xmpp

I want to check a xml string, wether that has the start and end specified tag in C#. 
The xml string is bellow.

```
string xml=@"<iq from='someone' to='someone' id='1234' type='result'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:hello' type='hello'><question questionid='17' postedon='1376148890' editedon='1376150411' categoryid='1034' categoryname='Computer' postedby='mohan' viewstatus='0' availability='offline'>Hello</question></query></iq>";

<iq from='someone' to='someone' id='1234' type='result'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:hello' type='hello'>
<question questionid='17' postedon='1376148890' editedon='1376150411' categoryid='1034' categoryname='Computer' postedby='mohan' viewstatus='0' availability='offline'>Hello</question>
</query>
</iq>
```

I have been using the following regex format to check but it doesn't help me

```
var regexForIq = new Regex(@"<iq(.*?)</iq>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var iqMatch = regexForIq.Match(_responseData);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to match HTML tags (applies to XML tags too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a real xml parser? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

```
var iq = XElement.Parse(xml).DescendantsAndSelf("iq").FirstOrDefault();
if (iq != null)
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also but if have an two root elements means which will throws the exception.Now i want to split two root <iq> elements to string array and then convert this to XElement

Comment: if you have multiple elements, why dont you create your own root element (temporary) and add all the string in that root element. Then try @I4V solution